# Gmail Alternate Username

Tags: gmail, google-account

On my Google Account link https://www.google.com/settings/personalinfo

My core Google account of coreAddressLongSilly@gmail.com

lists an
 **Alternate username** of *alterUser*

**Primary email**   *coreAddressLongSilly@gmail.com*

Question: how can I get access to the email of *alterUser@gmail.com* ?

I try to mail myself (to *alterUser@gmail.com*) but it bounces:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
>  alterUser@gmail.com
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: The email account that you
>   tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the
>   recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more
>   at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596

I try to create a new Gmail account with that username, but

https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail&hl=en

Tells me

> Someone already has that username. Try another?

Comment: Is this "Alternate" username in addition to "Recovery email" and "Other email" fields?   The Recovery address is used when you are not able to access your primary account.  This should have been previously verified.  The Other email address is also an alternate address for logging into your account.  You must already have access to both of these alternate accounts in order to use them with Google.

Comment: This username is not an email address at all. Nor a Nickname, which itself is listed higher up.

   One could say I am trying to turn this into an email (since as a gmail address it seems reserved for me already).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/70206?hl=en) has "If you previously used Gmail but decided to delete it from your Google Account, your old Gmail username will still appear on your Google Dashboard. You can still sign in with this username, but you won't be able to access your inbox."

[Recovering deleted username](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/67422) has:

> As long as you haven't deleted your entire Google Account, you may be able to regain use of your Gmail username by following these steps:

1. Sign in at https://www.google.com/accounts using the email address currently associated with your Google Account.
   Note: If you deleted Gmail from your account, but didn't delete your entire account, you'll most likely still be able to sign in with what was your alternate email address (now your primary username). If you're not able to sign in with this email address, you may have deleted your entire account. In this case, you won't be able to recover your Gmail username.
2. While still signed in to your Google Account, visit the Gmail sign-up page and your old Gmail username will be pre-populated in the username field.
3. Complete the form, enter your existing Google Account password, and click Continue.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to apply. 'alterUser' was never a deleted username. Also, in your step 2, not sure what URL you use for "Gmail sign-up page" but mine goes directly to my inbox, and valid email; since I am already logged in to my Google Account